# Move and turn an object in a grid with given command

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help on creating a small program to move an object in a 5*5 grid. I think I have to use a 2D array as the grid and move the object according to the given command. I can't find a way how to rotate the object clockwise 90 degrees and counterclockwise 90 degrees. Sample moving command is input like `(1,4,1,3,1,3,2)`

```
1 = go forward one block.
2 = go backwards one block.
3 = rotate clockwise 90 degrees.
4 = rotate counterclockwise 90 degrees.
```

So if the object started from (0,0) position heading to the south. Then after the above command, its location should be (2,2).

Can anyone suggest to me how to do this or have a sample code? The moving instruction is passed as command-line arguments.

Comment: What have you tried that you're having trouble with?

Comment: @xtratic    I have no idea how to keep the direction of facing. Basically, it says rotate 90 degrees. How to do this? I can move the object with the array index but how to turn it?

Comment: @everalian You may not need a 5x5 array if you can store the x and the y within the object itself. Similarly you can store the direction within the object itself let's say as an enum like N, S, W, E. If you are going to use a 2D array then it must be an array of cells that can store the direction and the id of the object that occupies that cell.

Comment: @corneliu  well thanks yes looks like I can store the facing direction on the object itself and move. However, I'm confused with later part. "If you are going to use a 2D array then it must be an array of cells that can store the direction and the id of the object that occupies that cell. "  can you explain this part more? Id of the object means what? array index? and how the array stores the direction?